# Colour/color space option for image textures in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, color-management

In the shader editor you can specify the colour space of your image texture. In particular, when creating height maps you can specify that the b&w image you’re using to determine the height is 'non-colour'.

In geometry nodes, there isn’t that option - i.e. there's no way of specifying an image as non-colour or RAW.

I'm using a 16-bit greyscale tiff as the heightmap/image texture in geometry nodes, and would be grateful for any advice as to whether that will alter the accuracy of the resulting height maps. And if so, if there's any way around this.

Many thanks

John

Answer (score 3):

In the *Geometry Node Editor* no additional options are displayed because the properties are strangely taken over exclusively from the values defined in the *Shader Editor*.

For example, if you add an `Image Texture` node in the *Shader Editor* and change the color space there, this also applies to the texture nodes used in the *Geometry Node Editor* that point to the same image.

To be honest, I don't understand why you can only change the color space in the *Shader Editor*, so you have to create an image texture node somewhere in the shader first, but it obviously only works that way.

Once you have configured the color space in any `Image Texture` node for your image, you can delete the node in the *Shader Editor* and nothing will change in the *Geometry Node Editor*.

[image]

Try it out for yourself:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an issue. Has it reported?

Comment: @Crantisz I assume that this is in addition to a large number of existing bugs ;-) But I honestly don't know if this has been reported yet (at least I haven't reported it so far). Where is the best place to do this?

Comment: Fun that you don't know. Help ⇾ Report Bug

Comment: @Crantisz Ahahaa, thanks, OK, I've never used this before :D ...whenever I find a bug, I try to find a way around it, because most of the time a change has already been made in the source code anyway that just hasn't made its way into a stable release yet.

Comment: Looks like a missing feature than a bug ... but it is always good to give a small push to a right direction :) Thanks

Comment: Missing feature reported: https://developer.blender.org/T102139