# How to use flowmap texture for rotation instances

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, vector-mapping

I wanted to use flowmap texture for direction / rotation of instances generated by geometry nodes.

I saw quite nice [explanation of basics behind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBEiTGHLkEo), but ... it says in one part - pure Green channel goes in up (Y) direction and later under color grid the same color is pointing to up-left direction. What I'm missing here?

[image]

Another story is ... When I tried to apply this grid texture to orient instances under GN it takes Red in X dir, Green in Y dir ... and completely ignores negative (dark) direction as shown in the grid texture.

[image]

What I'm missing in my node tree?

[image]

Basically I wanted to use awesome addon [Flowmap Painter](https://clemensbeute.gumroad.com/l/heZDT) (of Clemens Beute) to paint texture let instances orient in a brush movement ...

[image]

[image]

### Edit

Provided solution in answer works great ... Thank you guys :)

[image]

Comment: A color value is always positive, so you would have to map it to a range from $-1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if @Crantisz was once again faster, here nevertheless my answer to it, because here also the directions are treated correctly:

[image]

Note that the colors play an essential role here, as already discussed in this question:
[Colour/color space option for image textures in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261072/145249)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Will test it more ...

Comment: I had an issue with flowmap painter wrong orientation, than I noticed my grid texture in sample blend file (I took from net) was flipped on X compare to standard UV coordinates (like black at bottom-right should be at bottom-left). So I edit my picture and switched Map Range value for Red channel at your image. Anyway works nicely https://imgur.com/KnLZKJB ... I have also issue with using on sphere object, so probably I will ask for additional help later :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues here. First one, we need to tell Blender that we need non-color data. So that open your image in shader editor and change color space to Non-color or linear

[image]

Next, as  quellenform sad, you need to change the range of colors from 0...1 to -1...0, Or subtract 0.5

[image]

You should also make a Z-component based on the length of X+Y components

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Pedantic: I think you meant "...to -1...+1"?

Comment: Your node tree works for me for texture grid orientated with black bottom-left (that I flipped later). I skipped Z since it twisted instances a bit https://imgur.com/rXLGfLu ... what I can't figure out why bottom row (red) is slightly shifted down (and not 45 deg as quellenform's) https://imgur.com/FLgcB6N for uflowmap seems to be identical (or less noticeable?)