# Separate Colours "Value" value from geometry nodes does not seem to be correct

Tags: geometry-nodes, color

I'm trying to use a texture In geometry nodes. The texture in question is completely grey with an HSV color defined as 0,0,0.500 when creating the texture in the Image Editor.

Trying to extrapolate the HSV "Value" field from geometry nodes, it doesn't seem to match the 0.500 I set when creating the image. I use a custom "Named Attribute" to see the actual value, and it reports 0.216 (or 0.215 sometimes)

Here's a screenshot of my setup,

[image: my geometry nodes setup, with a test "named attribute" showing the problem]

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong since I'm very new to Geometry Nodes and Blender in general...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Here you will find the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255885/